# How to have ruby conditionally check if variables exist in a string?

Tags: ruby, liquid

So I have a string from a rendered template that looks like

```
"Dear {{user_name}},\r\n\r\nThank you for your purchase. If you have any questions, we are happy to help.\r\n\r\n\r\n{{company_name}}\r\n{{company_phone_number}}\r\n"
```

All those variables like `{{user_name}}` are optional and do not need to be included but I want to check that if they are, they have `{{` in front of the variable name. I am using liquid to parse and render the template and couldn't get it to catch if the user only uses 1 (or no) opening brackets. I was only able to catch the proper number of closing brackets. So I wrote a method to check that if these variables exist, they have the correct opening brackets. It only works, however, if all those variables are found.

here is my method:

```
  def validate_opening_brackets?(template)
    text = %w(user_name company_name company_phone_number)
    text.all? do |variable|
      next unless template.include? variable
      template.include? "{{#{variable}"
    end
  end
```

It works, but only if all variables are present. If, for example, the template created by the user does not include `user_name`, then it will return false. I've also done this loop using each, and creating a variable outside of the block that I assign `false` if the conditions are not met. I would really, however, like to get this to work using the `all?` method, as I can just return a boolean and it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is about how to rewrite the `all?` block to make it return `true` if all present variable names have two brackets before them and `false` otherwise then you could use something like this:

```
def validate_opening_brackets?(template)
  variables = %w(user_name company_name company_phone_number)
  variables.all? do |variable|
    !template.include?(variable) || template.include?("{{#{variable}")
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks so much! this worked to return false for improperly formatted variables that were included. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

There are multiple ways to do this, but the easiest way I can think of is to simply prefix/postfix a regular expression with the escaped characters used by Mustache/Liquid, and using alternation to check for each of your variable names within the template variable characters (e.g. double curly braces). You can then use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan) and then return a Boolean from [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) based on the contents of the Array returned by from #scan.

This works with your posted example, but there may certainly be other use cases where you need a more complex solution. YMMV.

### Example Code

This solution escapes the leading and trailing `{` and `}` characters to avoid having them treated as special characters, and then interpolates the variable names with `|` for alternation. It returns a Boolean depending on whether templated variables are found.

```rb
def template_string_has_interpolations? str
  var_names = %w[user_name company_name company_phone_number]
  regexp = /\{\{#{var_names.join ?|}\}\}/
  str.scan(regexp).any?
end
```

### Tested Examples

```rb
template_string_has_interpolations? "Dear {{user_name}},\r\n\r\nThank you for your purchase. If you have any questions, we are happy to help.\r\n\r\n\r\n{{company_name}}\r\n{{company_phone_number}}\r\n"
#=> true
```

```rb
template_string_has_interpolations? "Dear Customer,\r\n\r\nThank you for your purchase. If you have any questions, we are happy to help.\r\n\r\n\r\nCompany, Inc.\r\n(555) 555-5555\r\n"
#=> false
```

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to provide this! this is a really cool approach I wouldn't have thought of. I noticed, however, that it will return true still for improperly formatted variable, such as `{user_name}}`